# Parsing single CSV column delimited by ~HEADER@

Tags: php, parsing, csv, delimited

I have a CSV file which needs some additional processing. I've got most of our custom functionality completed. My stuck at the moment is the latest addition to the feed, multiple categories in 1 column. Here is a quick example of the new field setup.

```
Category01@Things~Category01@Will~Category01@Be~Category01@Here~Category02@Testing~Category02@More text here~Category02@Any data~Category02@No more data for this category~LastCategory@This~LastCategory@Is~LastCategory@The~LastCategory@End
```

I would need to build an array in PHP from each category available, similar to;

```
$category01 = array('Things', 'Will', 'Be', 'Here');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and the format correctly, categories separated by `~`, and each listed as `"SomeString@Category Name"`, then this should to the trick.  However I don't think this has anything to do with the CSV format.

```
$pairs = explode('~', $string);
$cats = array();
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    list($cat_number, $cat_name) = explode('@', $pair);
    $cats[] = $cat_name;
}
```

Comment: The data originally came in from a CSV import, but its now in our DB, awaiting further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Gahhh. the goggles, they do nothing!

If you're unable to change that output form (and it SHOULD be changed to something nicer), you'll have to go brute force:

```
$csv = '...';
$categories = array();
$parts = explode('~', $csv);
foreach($parts as $part) {
    $bits = explode('@', $part);
    $category = (int)substr($part[0], 8);
    if (!is_array($categories[$category])) {
        $categories[$category] = array();
    }
    $categories[$category][] = $part[1];
}
```

Of course, this'll blow up on your `LastCategory` stuff at the tail end  of that "csv". so... let me again STRONGLY urge you fix up whatever's generating that so-called "csv" in the first place.

Comment: Ya, thats what we're in the process of doing. I was hoping to find a simple solution which would allow us to at least display some of that data in the mean time. Thanks.